# Python thread with tkinter (threads can only be started once) - after checking if previous thread isAlive()

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have a GUI with a button. When the button is clicked I want it to run a background process (without freezing the GUI). I would also like to check the variables in the command window (Spyder).

1. The pseudo code below does the threading, but doesn't give control back at the command line.
2. When the button is pressed again, I get "RuntimeError: threads can only be started once" error. This is confusing. I am canceling the thread if it is alive and then starting it.

Any suggestions?

```
....
....
def timer_start(t):
    if t.isAlive():
        t.cancel()
    else:
        print('No threads are running')
    t.start()
...
...

import threading
timer = threading.Timer(0.1,clicked,[lbl])
timer.daemon = True

btn = ttk.Button(window, text="Start", command=lambda: timer_start(timer))
```

Comment: Not duplicate. isAlive() method is being used as suggested by that thread, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks. The logic is fine there. I want to cancel the thread if it is alive. Start the thread after killing it.

Comment: Thanks. "kill" is the wrong word here, but I am issuing a t.cancel() if it is alive then proceeding to start.

Comment: Read [threading.Thread.start](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) and [threading.Timer.cancel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer.cancel)